# Java StringBuffer doesn't change reference after extension

Tags: java, reference, stringbuffer

From the [StringBuffer docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html):

> Every string buffer has a capacity. As long as the length of the character sequence contained in the string buffer does not exceed the capacity, it is not necessary to allocate a new internal buffer array. If the internal buffer overflows, it is automatically made larger.

Based on my understanding, what that means is if we use `append` method to a string buffer and the length of the given string exceeds the capacity of the string buffer, JVM will automatically allocate some bigger memory to a new string buffer and store the old string buffer along with the given string. However, it this is the case, how can the old string buffer and the new string buffer have the same reference, just as indicated below. The appended string is larger than 16 bytes so this will force the JVM to allocate some new memory to the new string buffer.

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("initial value");

        System.out.println("before: the reference is " + System.identityHashCode(sb));

        sb.append(" - this message is append through sb and this message is longer than 16 bytes");

        System.out.println("after: the reference is " + System.identityHashCode(sb));
    }
}
```

the output

```
before: the reference is 511833308
after: the reference is 511833308
```

Comment: you posted it yourself: "...to allocate a new **internal** buffer array..." [:-) (and note documentation for `hashCode`: *may or **may not** be implemented as some function of an object's memory address*)

Answer (score 3):

There's a layer of indirection, as is usually the case. The actual character data is stored in a `char[]` object (typically). The same `StringBuffer` (or `StringBuilder`) instance changes its reference to the `char[]` from the old object to the new one. There is no *new* `StringBuffer`.

The Java source code of `java.lang.StringBuffer` (and parent class) is readily available if you want to look at that.

Comment: As you mentioned in your answer: "The same `StringBuffer` instance changes its reference to the `char[]` from the old object to the new one",  does this mean that the reference after appending will differ from the reference before appending? But this contradicts the output that I got, right?

Comment: @HongruLiu There's indirection. There's a reference inside the `StringBuffer` (to the `char[]`) as well as any references to the `StringBuffer` (which is entirely outside of the `StringBuffer`). Your code ----> `StringBuffer` ----> `char[]`. It's the latter arrow (reference) that changes.

Answer (score 0):

As already been said, after appending string, the `StringBuffer` reference doesn't changes, it still the same object.It just only allocating bigger array for storing characters. Also it worth mentioning that overriding `hashCode` to return hash of meaningful fields is a good practice, cause it will help you to track mutation of your object, but since `StringBuffer` doesn't override it, and since you call `System.identityHashCode`, it just always return initial object hash, that  doesn't change unless you assign another `StringBuffer` instance to `sb` variable. Last thing is that default `hashCode` implementation doesn't necessarily related to object reference, and you can't rely on that

Comment: Do you know any methods that could let me track the **real** reference of a `StringBuffer` before and after changing in Java?

Comment: The first thing that get on my mind, is to get `String` representation of `StringBuffer` before changing and compare with `String` representation after changing, but this leads to overhead cause every `StringBuffer.toString()` call will create new `String` instance. And probably StringBuffer is not what you need. Maybe look at apache common langs `StrBuilder` that override `hashCode` and show you the changes